# How to send a single-send email via exacttarget API via Ruby / Rails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ruby, ruby-on-rails

My goal is to send an email to our contactus@company.com email address when someone fills out our contact us form. We were previously using sendgrid, but have switched over to using Salesforce Exacttarget.

Is this possible with the Exacttarget API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll need to create an [**Email**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_overview/creating/), a Triggered Send Templated [**Data Extension**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) and a [**Triggered Send Definition**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/) (TSD).

Once the TSD is running, you can send an API call to fire off the email.

**Reference**

- [Triggered Email Scenario Guide For Developers](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/)
- [Send TriggeredSend Email](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/)

Answer (score 0):

As Adam mentioned, you will need to create an Email and Triggered Send Definition, then start the Triggered Send Definition.  Those steps can all be completed in the UI instead of using API calls.

The only API call you will need to make is the actual call to initiate the adhoc single email send using the definition you already created:

[Example Ruby Code for this call](https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-ruby/blob/master/samples/create_triggeredsend.rb)